# How to load a video in webView other than youtube

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, video, webview

i am trying to load a video from web in my webview, this video is not from youtube i am not getting how to load it can any one help me other than this code

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString*)url frame:(CGRect)frame
{
    NSString* embedHTML = @"<html><head> <style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color: transparent;color: white;}</style></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed></body></html>";
    NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];

  //  UIWebView *webView =[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [vebview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:vebview];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self embedYouTube:@"http://player.vimeo.com/video/32983838" frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 449)];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MPMoviePlayerController control for Playing Video.

Import `<MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>` framework into application.

.h File

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController;
```

.m File

```
-(void)startVideo:(NSString*)fileURL
{
   UIWebView *w = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
   w.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 340);
   w.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

   moviePlayerController = nil;
   CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 400);

   moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
   [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:rect];
   moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;


   [moviePlayerController play];

   [w addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
}
```

Here, I've used dynamic web-view inside view. You cn use it directly by XIB.

Hopefully, It'll helpful to you.

Thanks.

Comment: can i do without importing  media file or any other way?

Comment: i want for this link   http://player.vimeo.com/video/32983838